# why is my conditionals statement not working in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
import  random
import  sys 
import os 

print ("what is the password ?") 

instructions  =  ['-Press  [W]  To  Walk  Forward  (-Hold  [Left  Shift]  To Initiate Runing)','-Press [S] To Move Backwards' '-[A] For Left','-[D] For Right','-[space] For Jump']

password  =  sys.stdin.readline() 

if password =='food': 
      print  ("here"  )

for i in instructions: 
    print (i)

else: 
    print  ("not  correct")
```

The code I have entered is not working I have been stuck here since yesterday I am trying to learn python but I am stuck here please help me

Comment: You need to indent your `for` loop; you want an if-else construct not a for-else one

Comment: Storing a single string in a list (as in `instructions`) does not make much sense BTW

Comment: You should use `input()` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`. Input read using `sys.stdin.readline()` will contain a trailing newline.

Comment: Thank you, i was using a very old book ,i understand now

Comment: Please tell me more about lists and how i can write a better and improved  list

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
instructions  =  ['-Press  [W]  To  Walk  Forward  (-Hold  [Left  Shift]  To Initiate Runing)','-Press [S] To Move Backwards' '-[A] For Left','-[D] For Right','-[space] For Jump']

password = input("Enter password")

if password == "food":
      print("here")
      for i in instructions:
          print (i)

else:
    print("not correct")
```

Comment: Thank you so much this made my life easier

Comment: But its printing everything even with the wrong password

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
password  =  sys.stdin.readline()
```

Use following acordingly.

(Python 2)

```
password = raw_input()
```

(Python 3)

```
password = input()
```

Comment: Thank you i had no idea those functions existed, i almost wanted to switch to a different language